# Is Haste's "one weapon attack only text" a limitation on the action, or exactly what the action provides?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, attack

[SRD, page 97 - Haste](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf#97):

> That action can be used only to take the Attack (one weapon attack only), Dash, Disengage, Hide, or Use an Object action.

[SRD, page 27 - Fighter Extra Attack](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf#27):

> Beginning at 5th level, you can attack twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn.

[SRD, page 77 - Grappling](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf#77):

> When you want to grab a creature or wrestle with it, you can use the Attack action to make a special melee attack, a grapple. If you’re able to make multiple attacks with the
> Attack action, this attack replaces one of them.

Is there any indication or rule provided for if the text *(one weapon attack only)* in Haste is specifying what the Attack Action provides or if this is a limitation placed on the Attack Action?

The former means that shoves, grapples, and any other rule or feature that replaces Attacks would not be valid with the 2nd attack provided by Extra Attack or Haste's Attack Action at all.

The latter means that it is valid to make one weapon attack, then use the other attack from Extra Attack to do anything else available to a creature that is not a weapon attack.

Comment: Related Question: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77612/haste-spell-what-does-one-weapon-attack-only-mean

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate, this seems like the same question as related one you linked.

Comment: Related/Duplicate: "[Haste spell: what does "one weapon attack only" mean?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/77612)" and "[Can the additional attack action granted by Haste be used to shove a creature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/134599)" and "[Does Extra Attack stack with Haste?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/100601)". Additional reading on how *haste* interacts with: [Unleash Incarnation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/167753), [Horde Breaker](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/125161), and [Stalker's Flurry](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/125161)

Answer (score 1):

### Haste does not give you a full Attack action, just a single weapon attack

You have the text right there:

> That action can be used only to take the Attack (**one weapon attack only**), Dash, Disengage, Hide, or Use an Object action.

If the extra parenthesis would not be there, then you could take a full attack action, including Extra Attack attacks. But Haste explicitly limits you to a [single weapon attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77612/haste-spell-what-does-one-weapon-attack-only-mean) with your Attack action.

The spell only does [what it says](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107637/what-is-the-source-of-the-spells-do-only-what-they-say-they-do-rules-interpret). There are many other actions that Haste does not allow you to do, because it does not say so, for example you cannot cast a spell with the Haste action, cannot take the Dodge action, and likewise you cannot Shove, or Grapple, as neither is a weapon attack, nor is it separately listed.

Comment: Downvoters: I am puzzled if you think the answer is technically incorrect, or you feel like punishing an answer under a closed question. Please let me know if the first, because I think it is correct and would like to learn where I misunderstand something

Comment: FWIW, I upvoted.

Comment: This was the focus of my question, and why I thought it worth creating a new one: *"Is there any indication or rule provided for if the text (one weapon attack only) in Haste is specifying what the Attack Action provides or if this is a limitation placed on the Attack Action?"* Based on your answer, it's "No", but I think the downvotes are indicative of the problem I'm pointing out: It's vague. There's no real indication of either/or, except what one wants to assume. You are choosing the more restrictive reading, but there's nothing provided for why the restrictive reading is correct.

Comment: @PaydenK.Pringle I went through all the listed duplicates and then some, and I've not found any reading that differs from this answer. Could you point me to one?